# Blue prism doesn't recognize inputs in my WSDL

Tags: wsdl, business-process-management, blueprism

I have a WSDL created by a BPM tool and it has username, password, and an business specific input. I tried calling that web service from SOAP UI. It prompted me for all the three inputs and I was able to call the WSDL successfully.

In Blue prism when I tried the same, it doesn't recognize my WSDL inputs and outputs. I confirmed it by checking the "Importing web service definitions" screen and by checking the inputs outputs in the "Action" stage.

When I tried creating a web service from the same Blue prism instance and tried calling in the same Blue prism environment, this issue didn't occur. I checked the WSDL of BPM and WSDL of Blue prism and both seems to be the same.

Anybody came across this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WSDL support in Blue Prism isn't so great with WSDLs generated by certain engines.

The way to counteract this is to use a utility like SoapUI to generate the sample calls for you and model them within the parameters of the `Utility - HTTP` Business Object's `HTTP Request` Action.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I can achieve this using an http call. Is there anyway that I can call this WSDL? Can I do some changes to make web service call working? Because I have some limitation in the BPM's side in making http call.